# Prevent access outside of class

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I would like to restrict a class to only access its members and nothing more, in order to explicitly minimize the side effects on that class.

In the end the compiler should give an error if e.g. anything from the global namespace is used. As I think this is not possible in stock C++, is there a compiler extension, that does such checks at compile time?

EDIT:

Optimal I would have to enable all global namespace objects, functions, etc. I would like to allow to be used.

Comment: Define "outside the class". Do you also want the class to not use things like `int`, `=` and `if`?

Comment: Is this a class your implementing or someone else ?

Comment: It doesn't seem unreasonable to restrict a class to only _change_ its own local variables.  It's less reasonable to keep a class from accessing other variables, and not very reasonable at all to keep a class from using external functions.  However, you might be able to build a pre-processor step that checks for #includes or externs.  If those exist (beyond the ones necessary), it could complain.

Comment: Counter-question: why do you need such tight restrictions?

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Me and others. So more than 1 person may make such a mistake.

Comment: @LCIDFire: I can see why one will want that, it could benefit in unit-testing etc. but I can't think of a way to do it. that's interesting. +1

Comment: @Simone Because I cross-compile to a very strange target and e.g. accessing globals *will* break at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I missed something but if you don't include any other header file, you won't have access to anything else than your class.

Comment: Not true. A programmer could always declare an _extern_ and you lost again.

Comment: I think this is the only standard way to do it.

Comment: @LCIDFire: I don't understand. If you don't include the header where this extern is defined you won't be able to access it.

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD he will, if the extern var exists in a file the linker is linking against.

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD As long as the signature matches you can _declare_ an `extern` at any point and access it.

Comment: @LCIDFire: again maybe I missed something but you have to declare this extern in your class too.

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD The point is that you can. Anyone working on the code can. And I know no way of _enforcing_ that nobody can - to be on the safe side.

Comment: @LCIDFire: ok I understand better. Maybe c++ is not the right language so because there are lots of thing that you can do but should not (that's also why it is so fun :))

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is possible. If you want to have a variable and make sure a class isn't accessing it. make it a NON-global variable and pass it only to the relevant classes